# F2 button does not rename file in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

In Windows 7, my <kbd>F2</kbd> button does not rename my files. Why? And how to fix it?

My Windows 7 is 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in [this Microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/my-f2-key-doesnt-work-for-rename-win7/44eb3a79-4b9d-4330-9098-07b09b18ac2d), check to see if you have installed Babylon Dictionary or Ginger It, either of which may be using the <kbd>F2</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to press the fn key to get <kbd>F2</kbd> to activate the rename functionality. On my HP laptop <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> control the screen brightness (without the <kbd>fn</kbd> key). When I press <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> I can rename files.

Answer (score 0):

I have a programmable Microsoft wirelesess keyboard and mouse model 3000.
Easy solution: The blue Function lock was ON !
F2 Rename is now working.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.